# Multicollinearity Multiple Choice Question

Tags: regression, self-study, econometrics, multicollinearity

I have one exam question. Anyone can answer and explain the reason for me?

> You are studying the following
>   $$
> Y = \beta_0 +\beta_1X_1 +β_2X_2 +u.
> $$
>   You know that the two variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ are positively correlated. To avoid multi- collinearity you use the following simplified model instead:
>   $$
> Y = \tilde{β}_0 +\tilde{β}_2X_2 +u
> $$
>   What should you expect if the true model is such that $β_1 < 0$ and $β_2 > 0$? 
>   Which of the following is correct (Multiple choice)?
>
> 1. $\mathbb{E}(\hat{\tilde{β}}_0)=β_0$
> 2. $\mathbb{E}(\hat{\tilde{β}}_2)=β_2$
> 3. $\mathbb{E}(\hat{\tilde{β}}_2)>β_2$
> 4. $\mathbb{E}(\hat{\tilde{β}}_0)<β_0$
> 5. $\mathbb{E}(\hat{\tilde{β}}_2)<β_2$

---

X1 and X2 are positively correlated If we omit X1 and true β1<0, so (β ̂2)<β2 (it should be the same sign because of positively correlated). Is it correct? However, I don't understand why this question have to mention about β2>0 ?

Comment: If it is an exam question show us what you tried as for now.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read [its wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to help you get unstuck. We will not answer this for you.

Comment: A good way to think about this question is to consider the extreme case where $X_2$ is a positive multiple of $X_1$ (that is, perfect correlation), for then you can easily and explicitly write down the new estimates in terms of the old ones. That ought to shed light on why the signs of $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ matter so much.